# Android Socket communication Exception

Tags: android, client

My server code

```
 public class RemoteServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("Listening :8888");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF().toUpperCase());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("sajol");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
     }
```

My client code for android device

```
public class Client extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Button b = findViewById(R.id.b)

    textOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t);
    Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.te);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    }
};
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.239", 8888);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
            textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Sajol", e+"");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Sajol", e+"");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Sajol", e+"");
                }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Sajol", e+"");
                }
            }

            if (dataInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    dataInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Sajol", e+"");
                }
            }
        }







    }
};
  }
```

when i run this client code on emulator server response .But when i run client code on real device server program does not response.I found the ip address using in my code by execute ipconfig command on cmd. My pc(windows 7) and android device both are connected to wifi.

i got following exception

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out

Please give me solution

Comment: Install Fing program on Android device and check network configuration and available servers. Possibly this is some network problem, not related to the program.

Comment: Are both, server and device connected to same wifi router?

Comment: i install fing and it show my pc ip address.And my pc ip is 192.168.1.239 @AlexFarber

Comment: Now try to use "Test IP address" Fing function, which allows to send/receive strings - it implements IP client code.